# Landscape Dialog with Portrait Activity

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I have an `Activity` that has `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` options set in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

At all times, I want this `Activity` to stay in `portrait` mode.

However, one of the buttons opens a dialog that has `SignaturePad` widget, provided by [this](https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad) library.

Because user has to sign with their finger/stylus, I want to make the `Dialog` landscape so there is more space to sign.

Is it possible to change `Dialog`'s orientation without changing the `Activity`'s orientation?

I've tried `DialogFragment`, system level dialog (`TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`) and few other things. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: When you want to show dialog : getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Comment: That will change the Activity in the background to be landscape. My layout isn't setup to be landscape and it looks really messy in the background. I'm looking for a way around that